# tsqlt AssertEqualsTable chops middle part of wide column

Tags: sql-server, unit-testing, tsqlt

Using tSQLt, I'm testing a proc that produces long text columns as output.  I use AssertEqualsTable with an empty table to compare to the output, so that I can see all the output generated.  (is there a better way to do that?)

I'm seeing output like this (from a row that is longer than 156 characters):

foofoofoofoofoo<...>barbarbarbarbar

how can I see what is being chopped out?

Sample:

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.temptable ( [m] int  NOT NULL ,  [p] int  NOT NULL ,  CONS<...>R TABLE [RotatePartitions].[TestTable] SWITCH PARTITION 1 TO dbo.temptable;
```

the string CONS begins a constraint definition, but it is chopped off.  Similarly at the other end, "R TABLE" should be "ALTER TABLE"

Comment: This is the output in messages or results tab?

Comment: Either!  I'm not fussy.

Comment: I was asking where are you seeing this truncation at? It sounds like the Results pane in SSMS when you are viewing Results to Grid. If you change your result output to Result to Text at the top of SSMS, you should see the entire string.

Comment: Yeah in the Results,  Also in XML output.  Even when Result to Text is on.  e.g.  I see: ""CREATE TABLE dbo.temptable ( [m] int  NOT NULL ,  [p] int  NOT NULL ,  CONS<...>R TABLE [RotatePartitions].[TestTable] SWITCH PARTITION 1 TO dbo.temptable;""